# How to define a public const string in a repository that implements an interface

Tags: c#

I have a `Controller`class which makes use of a `TodoRepository`class via DI that implements an interface `ITodoRepository`.

The interface:

```
public interface ITodoRepository
{
    public bool ValidateTodo(Todo todo);
}
```

The repository class:

```
public class TodoRepository : ITodoRepository
{
    public bool ValidateTodo(Todo todo)
    {
        //some validation
        return false;
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
public TodoController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ITodoRepository _todoRepository;
    private const string INVALID_TODO_MESSAGE = "Invalid todo.";

    public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoRepository)
    {
        _todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Post(Todo todo)
    {
        if(!_todoRepository.ValidateTodo(todo))
        {
            return new JsonResult(INVALID_TODO_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

To be able to use `INVALID_TODO_MESSAGE` in every `Controller` that makes use of `TodoRepository` I want to move it to `TodoRepository`, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Some other solution is to create a readonly property in `ITodoRepository`, and implement it in `TodoRepository`, but I am not sure if that is the best way to go.

Comment: You could always create a base repository, implement the read only property there and derive all other repositories from the base? You could always go further and make the property virtual in the base should any other classes need to override it.

Comment: Yes to the other solution. Define a getter for the message in the interface.

Comment: Does the (content of) the error message really belong to the contract?

Comment: The obvious path here would be a separate, shared, class (or even assembly) to hold the strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a helper class, next to the interface:

```
public static class TodoConstants
{
    public const string INVALID_TODO_MESSAGE = "Invalid todo.";
}
```

You can use it everywhere as `TodoConstants.INVALID_TODO_MESSAGE`.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: This is not a direct answer to the question, but rather a design suggestion for error handling in web applications.

I would implement such a validation using `Exception`s. Typically you could throw business exceptions from your application layer (possibly including repository too). Then at the web layer (aka. controllers, filters, etc.) you could implement an `ExceptionFilter` to handle business exceptions, for example turning them into a special `JsonResult`.

This way you'll have a good separation of concerns and centralized error handling through the application.

See this documentation for ASP.NET WebApi (it's almost the same for MVC too) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Some untested pseudo code would look like this.

```
public class TodoRepository : ITodoRepository
{
    public bool ValidateTodo(Todo todo)
    {
        //some validation
        throw new ValidationException("Invalid todo");
    }
}

public class MyBusinessExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{        
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        ...
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult(filterContext.Exception.Message);
        ...
    }
}

public static void ApplicationStartup() {
    ...
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyBusinessExceptionFilterAttribute());
    ...
}

public IActionResult Post(Todo todo)
{
    // Just let the exception to be thrown in case of business errors
    _todoRepository.ValidateTodo(todo);
}
```

Comment: This is a) not really an answer on where to keep the messages and b) rather dubious advice. It depends a lot on what kind of validation this is.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've added this as a disclaimer, however I feel this might be a good indirect answer though. In my opinion a thin controller is a good pattern in almost every case.